# How can the modulo function be used to work out what day of the week a certain date falls on?

Tags: java

Pardon me if it's not the right place to post, but I'm so curious about this.
So December 5th is a date. Last year it fell on a Tuesday.
How can modulo be used to work this out?

I know this is a modulo problem, but just don't get how modulo is used here.

Comment: `if 34 % 1 == 0 { birthday = Wednesday;` in all honesty, this question is quite unclear.

Comment: @achAmháin where's 34 from?

Comment: It’s irrelevant; I made it up. Point being, how would we know the answer as it’s a rather broad unclear question with nothing to go on. Have you an example somewhere or perhaps even a [mcve]?

Comment: If a given year is not a leap year, then it has 365 days.  365 days is 52 weeks and one day (365 modulo 7 = 1) therefore the next year the birthday will fall on the day following the current year's weekday.  If it were a leap year, the result would be two therefore it would be two days after.

Comment: why neative vote :<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A famous algorithm for calculating the day of the week based on the date is [Zeller's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeller%27s_congruence). If you follow that link to wikipedia, you will see the algorithm, which uses the modulus operator.

It is used to calculate the year of the century (denoted K) by doing
`current year % 100`

It's also used at the end of the expression, where we calculate modulo 7 of the formula shown on wikipedia:

https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/0f95195dcc0d98b351294277071736e97053324e

With a little intuition, you will realize 7 is used because there are 7 days in the week.